# instantiateResampleInstance.CVDesc: too many folds for size

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr

Working on parameter tuning an xgboost model, and ran into an interesting error in my implementation of mlr, which I believe caused by my resample instance [due to the documentation here](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/master/R/ResampleInstances.R). the problem is I can't quite track down how to fix it. I've tried manually setting the size param for the function, but that is also rejected.

basic code:

```
samplecount = sample.split(test_train,SplitRatio = 0.8)

stest <- subset(test_train,samplecount ==TRUE)



strain <- subset(test_train,samplecount ==FALSE)

new_tr <- model.matrix(~.+0,data = subset(strain,select=-c(Value))) 

new_ts <-  model.matrix(~.+0,data = subset(stest,select=-c(Value))) 

labels <- strain$Value
labels <- as.numeric(labels)-1

ts_label <- stest$Value
ts_label <- as.numeric(ts_label)-1

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_tr,label = labels)


dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = new_ts,label=ts_label)

params <- list(booster = "gbtree", objective = "reg:linear", 
               eta=0.3, gamma=0, max_depth=6, min_child_weight=1, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1)

xgbcv <- xgb.cv( params = params, data = dtrain, 
                 nrounds = 100,  showsd = T,nfold=5,
                 stratified = T, print.every.n = 1, early.stop.round = 20, maximize = F)


xgb1 <- xgb.train (params = params, data = dtrain, nrounds = 79, watchlist = list(val=dtest,train=dtrain), print.every.n = 10, early.stop.round = 10, maximize = F , eval_metric = "error")

xgbpred <- predict (xgb1,dtest)



mat <- xgb.importance (feature_names = colnames(new_tr),model = xgb1)
 xgb.plot.importance (importance_matrix = mat[1:20]) 

 #convert characters to factors
  fact_col <- colnames(strain)[sapply(strain,is.character)]

  for(i in fact_col) set(strain,j=i,value = factor(strain[[i]]))
  for (i in fact_col) set(stest,j=i,value = factor(stest[[i]]))

  ## this seems like an odd add, but for the steps

  strain$Value <- as.factor(strain$Value)

  stest$Value <- as.factor(stest$Value)

 #create tasks
  traintask <- makeClassifTask (data = strain,target = "Value",fixup.data = "no")
  testtask <- makeClassifTask (data = stest,target = "Value",fixup.data = "no")

 #do one hot encoding`<br/> 
  traintask <- createDummyFeatures (obj = traintask) 
  testtask <- createDummyFeatures (obj = testtask)



 lrn <- makeLearner("regr.xgboost",predict.type = "response")
  lrn$par.vals <- list( objective="reg:linear", eval_metric="error", nrounds=100L, eta=0.1)

 #set parameter space
  params <- makeParamSet( makeDiscreteParam("booster",values = c("gbtree","gblinear")),
                          makeIntegerParam("max_depth",lower = 3L,upper = 10L),
                          makeNumericParam("min_child_weight",lower = 1L,upper = 10L), 
                          makeNumericParam("subsample",lower = 0.5,upper = 1), 
                          makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree",lower = 0.5,upper = 1))

 #set resampling strategy
  rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV",stratify = T,iters=5L)


  ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10L)  


  library(parallel)
   library(parallelMap) 
   parallelStartSocket(cpus = detectCores())


  #parameter tuning
  mytune <- tuneParams(learner = lrn, task = traintask, resampling = rdesc, , measures = acc, par.set = params, control = ctrl, show.info = T)

Error in instantiateResampleInstance.CVDesc(desc, length(ci), task) : 
  Cannot use more folds (5) than size (1)!
```

From there I tried:

```
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV",stratify = T,size=5)
Error in makeResampleDescCV(size = 5) : unused argument (size = 5)
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size is not a parameter in `makeResampleDesc`. I think (not completely sure), that your problem is, that you do not have enough observations for certain classes and then you cannot do stratification.

Try using: `rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV",stratify = F,iters=5)`

Comment: that absolutely worked. Can you say something about how this works methodologically? doing this to gain better understanding of the process/methods so I'd be very interested.

Comment: You cannot have more folds than minimum size of a class. That is a bit arbitrary from mlr side. But if you have less than 5 observations for one class you should also really think of excluding this class/observations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the `stratify` term in the `makeResampleDesc` function. We generally use the stratification approach as a statistical methodology to grasp confounding, i.e. confusion in classification using models.

You can read about the theory and reasoning (implemented in Python) [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-magic-of-stratification-in-data-analysis-f1ee4800a283).

In your dataset, if there are classes of the `target` variable that have very few entries (less than 5), then the `makeResampleDesc` function is unable to perform a resampling instance for that specific class.

As stated above, setting `stratify = F` will fix the issue here, but I would look into this and would `oversample` any class with a small number of observations, or alternatively, `holdout` [(read here)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlr/versions/2.19.0/topics/makeResampleDesc) from training initially to understand how the rest of the classes are being categorized before simply disregarding the `stratify` method.

What you can do to understand which classes are with few observations is look at the frequency and make decisions from there using the following line:

```
library("data.table")

table(daraframe$target)
```

In my case, I had few instances of class `GG3` so that stopped me from being able to `stratify` the data, see below:

[image]